# make error: "make[1]: *** [directories] Error 1"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I try to run "make all" on a makefile with some complexity I get this errors:

```
C:\BITCLOUD\BitCloud_PS_SAM3S_EK_1_10_0\BitCloud_PS_SAM3S_EK_1_10_0\Applications\ZAppSi\Dem o\SEDevice>make all 
make -C makefiles/PC -f Makefile_PC_Gcc all APP_NAME=DemoSE
make[1]: Entering directory
'C:/BITCLOUD/BitCloud_PS_SAM3S_EK_1_10_0/BitCloud_PS_SAM3S_EK_1_10_0/Applications/ZAppSi/Demo/SEDevice/makefiles/PC'
A sintaxe do comando está incorrecta.
make[1]: *** [directories] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory
'C:/BITCLOUD/BitCloud_PS_SAM3S_EK_1_10_0/BitCloud_PS_SAM3S_EK_1_10_0/Applications/ZAppSi/Demo/SEDevice/makefiles/PC'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

where the line

```
A sintaxe do comando está incorrecta.
```

translated to english means: "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

I already tried to change the project to different directories, check spaces in file names, using GNU make and also use MinGW make (mingw32-make) and the result is the same with both "make". I also checked for all files that are included in the makefile and they correspond.

Im not an expert in makefiles, so Im asking for help.
What is the main problem that occurs when make throws this type of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely not `make` that throws this error, but a command executed by make returns with a nonzero exit status, in this case with status 1 (due to Error 1); then the top level `make` stops with Error 2. Note that `make` by default stops as soon as a command fails.
Since the output doesn't show what command was executed, there is no way to tell what went wrong exactly.

**EDIT**: from the GNU make manual:

> ```
>    -d   Print debugging information in addition  to  normal  processing.
>         The  debugging information says which files are being considered
>         for remaking, which file-times are being compared and with  what
>         results,  which files actually need to be remade, which implicit
>         rules are considered and which are  applied---everything  inter‐
>         esting about how make decides what to do.
>
>    --debug[=FLAGS]
>         Print  debugging  information  in addition to normal processing.
>         If the FLAGS are omitted, then the behavior is the same as if -d
>         was specified.  FLAGS may be a for all debugging output (same as
>         using -d), b for basic  debugging,  v  for  more  verbose  basic
>         debugging,  i for showing implicit rules, j for details on invo‐
>         cation of commands, and m for  debugging  while  remaking  make‐
>         files.
> ```

I suggest running `make --debug=j` to see the commands.

Comment: How can I "debug" properly my makefile in order to see if something is wron? Any hints?